# Upload Data into MongoLab database from terminal

Tags: mongodb, csv, import, mlab

I'm having trouble figuring out how to upload csv data to my MongoLab database. From my terminal I have used

```
sudo mongoimport --db heroku_hkr86p3z -u <dbusername> -p <dbpassword> --collection contributors --type csv --headerline --file /Users/tonywinglau/Desktop/independent-expenditure.csv
```

and

```
sudo mongoimport --host mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds035310.mlab.com:35310/heroku_hkr86p3z --db heroku_hkr86p3z -u <username> -p <password> --collection contributors --type csv --headerline --file /Users/tonywinglau/Desktop/independent-expenditure.csv
```

both of which respond with

```
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
imported 0 documents
```

From what I have read it might be something to do with my 'mongo config' file (I can't find it if it does exist) being set to only connect with localhost? How do I import data directly into my mongolab hosted database?

Comment: This isn't really a question for stackoverflow, though people may have left around similar attempt with similar responses to this. This means of course the the host either has the wrong name or is simply not actively running. I can `ping` the host, so the name looks good. But I should be able to do `mongo mongodb://ds03510.mlab.com:3510` and get a connection ( even if not authenticated ) but I cannot. This means that the database instance is either not running or current firewall rules are not allowing connection from the public internet. Same reason is why you cannot connect.

Comment: Can you connect with the `mongo` shell? http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help

Comment: Yes I can connect with the shell. The problem is mongo import is supposed to be run outside of shell. right now i'm just trying to create a function that can parse the csv into json and then spam POSTs to my database. idk. Thats just my current thought.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Wouldn't sudo override firewall settings?

Comment: Sudo has nothing to do with this. If you can connect with the shell then you can connect with `mongoimport`. You simply are not providing the correct options or credentials. Should have `--host ds03510.mlab.com` and `--port 3510` and username and password options of course where required.

Answer (score 4):

Your command line should look like this:

```
mongoimport -d <databasename> -c <collectionname> --type csv --file <filelocation/file.csv> --host <hostdir example:ds011291.mlab.com> --port <portnumber example:11111> -u <username> -p <password> --headerline
```

The host direction and the port number it gived by mlab when you create the database.
Example:

```
ds000000.mlab.com:000000/databaseName
```